# Github error: failed to push some refs to github.com

Tags: github

I have installed the git ,created repository , then I have tried to push from vs code to github repository with cmd

```
git push -u origin main
```

Git say error: failed to push some refs to  'github.com:loobj126/boredape-dapp-bj.git''

What's the problem?

https://github.com/loobj126/boredape-dapp-bj

[image]

i ve few approach yet still not resolve

https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-git-errors/

[image]

**Latest input :**

after initialize

```
[2022-04-20T08:44:06.669Z] Validating found git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
[2022-04-20T08:44:06.796Z] Using git 2.35.3.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
[2022-04-20T10:45:43.723Z] > git init [128ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:44.399Z] > git rev-parse --git-dir [72ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:44.403Z] Open repository: c:\Users\loobj\boredape-dapp-bj
[2022-04-20T10:45:44.606Z] > git fetch [197ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:44.676Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [119ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:44.765Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [85ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:44.872Z] > git remote --verbose [99ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:44.888Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [119ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:45.019Z] > git config --get commit.template [122ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:45.040Z] > git config --local branch.master.github-pr-owner-number [121ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:45.300Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [101ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:45.385Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [80ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:45.490Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [101ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:45.507Z] > git remote --verbose [115ms]
[2022-04-20T10:45:45.589Z] > git config --get commit.template [76ms]
```

Click push

[image]
[image]

[2022-04-20T10:59:18.763Z] > git push boredape-dapp-bj master [153ms]
[2022-04-20T10:59:18.763Z] error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/loobj126/boredape-dapp-bj.git'
[2022-04-20T11:00:41.028Z] > git fetch [141ms]
[2022-04-20T11:00:41.220Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [68ms]
[2022-04-20T11:00:41.286Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [63ms]
[2022-04-20T11:00:41.380Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [91ms]
[2022-04-20T11:00:41.394Z] > git remote --verbose [102ms]
[2022-04-20T11:00:41.485Z] > git config --get commit.template [84ms]

Comment: can you paste full error message(not in image format)?

Comment: added latest input how does it happen

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1:** for error: src refspec master does not match any.
All you need to perform is git commit with a proper message and then do git push to the remote origin to avoid any errors.

```
mkdir repo && cd repo
git remote add origin /path/to/origin.git
git add .

git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

**Solution 2** – First, check what refs you have, and once you find that, make a git push to the specific remote branch.

```
# To get all the ref 
git show-ref

# replace with your branch name according to ref 
git push origin HEAD:<branch>
```

this worked for me.

Comment: i try run 'git show-ref' but no result.


loobj@LAPTOP-SACR77J5 MINGW64 ~/boredape-dapp-bj (master)
$ git show-ref

loobj@LAPTOP-SACR77J5 MINGW64 ~/boredape-dapp-bj (master)
$

Comment: for solution (1) , it hits below error


loobj@LAPTOP-SACR77J5 MINGW64 ~/boredape-dapp-bj (master)
$ git push origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, go on and run following commands:

git pull --rebase origin main

git push -u origin main

If the first command above runs successfully, you should get a response that says: Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.

The second command pushes your local repo's current state to the remote branch.

ref: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-how-to-fix-in-git/

Answer (score 0):

It might also be problem of branching, you're in different branch *`master`* whereas the remote branch is *`main`*:

- List all branches:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

- Create and switch to the same branch of remote repo:

```
$ git checkout -b main
Switched to a new branch 'main'
```

- Push to the remote branch:

```
$ git push origin main
```